# Java - Am i correctly reading the text from this file?

Tags: java, syntax

I am curious if I am reading the text (correctly) from this file.

Purpose: Read text from a file and place it into a Set named "lines" (the set is a LinkedHashSet because I am supposed to have the elements sorted in the order they were added).

Here is the code from the main() function (imports omitted):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Set<FileExaminer> examiners = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        examiners.add(new FileExaminer("raven.txt"));
        examiners.add(new FileExaminer("jabberwocky.txt"));

        for (FileExaminer fe : examiners) {
            System.out.println("-----------------------");
            fe.display(45);
            System.out.println();
            fe.displayCharCountAlpha();
            fe.displayCharCountNumericDescending();
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Here is the LinkedHashSet's creation:

```
private LinkedHashSet< String > lines = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Here is the code from the FileExaminer class that is being referenced here:

```
public FileExaminer(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(file);

    if(file.exists()){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(filename);

        /** Read the contents of the file and place them into the lines set */
        while( reader.hasNext() ){
            lines.add( reader.next() );
        } // end of while
        reader.close();
    } // end of if
    else{
        /** Throw exception if the file does not exist */
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found: " + filename);
    } // end of else

    /** Call calculateCharCountAlpha */
    calculateCharCountAlpha();
} // end of constructor
```

The issue that I am having, is in the output of the program. 
When I print out desired lines from the "lines" Set, I am getting the filename, and when I print out the items in the other Sets from my other methods, it works correctly, but it is analyzing the filename, NOT the text in the file. 
I am unsure why this is the case.

I have already posted the code for displayCharCountAlpha in a previous question (it was found to work correctly), so I won't include that.

displayCharCountAlpha():

```
public void displayCharCountAlpha(){ // prints out charCountAlpha
    System.out.println(charCountAlpha);
}
```

displayCharCountNumericDescending():

```
public void displayCharCountNumericDescending() { // prints out charCountNumericDescending
    System.out.println(charCountNumericDescending);
}
```

display():

```
public void display(int numberOfLines){
    int count = 0; // control-variable that can be checked throughout iteration
    for(String s : lines){
        System.out.println(s);
        count++;

        if(count == numberOfLines-1){ // number of lines insinuates that the loop has the set amount of times
            break; // break out of the loop
        } // end of if
    } // end of for
} // end of Display()
```

Comment: Change the fifth line of `FileExaminer` to `Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);`

Comment: I made this change. I am getting nothing for an output. Does it look like I correctly read in the contents of the file? Note: The file is Edgar Allen Poe's poem, "Raven".

Comment: Well, you haven't shown the code for `display`, `displayCharCountAlpha` and `displayCharCountNumericDescending` so I would require psychic powers to help you further.

Comment: Okay, sure thing! I will post the code for you to see

Comment: I have now included the code. Thank you for the quick replies. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple bug,

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(filename);
```

should be

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
```

Currently, you read from the `String` `filename` (and you want to read from the `File` `file`).

Comment: I now see that, thank you! I am now having the issue of not having anything for an output. Does it look like I read in the strings, incorrectly?

Comment: @Tobymac208 It appears like you read them in **correctly** (if you've made this change). Time to use your debugger. Also, you might consider posting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Here is an isolated bit of code, that results in the same error: 'code' try {
            File file = new File("raven.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                String a = scanner.next();
                System.out.println(a);
            }

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } 'code'

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the file I was reading from, not the algorithms that I used.
Seems that the format of the text was the main issue.
I took the text that was the file, used a program to write all of the text to the file, used the same file again, and it worked! 
Strange problem, but it's fixed. A big thank you to everyone that helped out!